# VspPHPKit Form Integration - 5080 : ERROR : Form transaction registration failed

Tags: opayo

I am trying to use the VspPHPKit and configured it for form integration and whilst testing; I am getting this error:

> 5080 : ERROR : Form transaction registration failed.

Looking into this error message; I came across this page: https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/error-codes/5080-error-form-transaction-registration-failed

I've tried the solution; there was nothing in my invalid transaction tab. Then I've looked at this note: **encryption passwords for both TEST and LIVE are different.**

This is not the case for me, my **live & test** account both appears have the *same* form encryption password?

How is this possible and how can I change the form password? I don't see an option on the user interface even after logging in an account administrator (i.e. username and vendor name same).

Comment: If you log in as the vendor name, the option to reset the Form password is certainly there, in the "admin" link on the left hand side. Live and test *can* be the same by chance, or perhaps if Sage Pay migrate a test account to a live account, but the point the documentation is trying to make is that they are *independent*.

Comment: The error `5080` is a generic error that means "something is not right". It is next to useless. If any mandatory fields are missing, or any non-expected fields are set (e.g. `foo=bar`), then you will get this error. So your application needs to be very, very careful that it constructs the field list properly and validly before sending the user off to the gateway.